# How to get a list of products by ItemID Ebay SDK

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I would like to get a list of products filtered by their ItemID ?
I successfully retrieved a list of products filtered by date using the GetSellerList Call on Ebay SDK.
I saw there is a kind of getItem method but it seems to return only one item. Is there a way to do it without calling multiple times the getItem API method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/shopping/docs/CallRef/GetMultipleItems.html

```
I think You are looking for GetMultipleItems() method from ebaysdk.shopping as above.     
You can retrieve maximum 20 items per one query.
```